# What are the type conversion rules for using a spread syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am reading over the documentation for spread syntax. In particular, I'm looking for the JavaScript type conversion rules used to spread the values of a variable into an object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

For example;

```
let x = "abc";
console.log({...x}); // prints "{0:'a',1:'b',2:'c'}"

x = 123;
console.log({...x}); // prints "{}"

x = true;
console.log({...x}); // prints "{}"

x = [1,2,3];
console.log({...x}); // prints "{0:1,1:2,2:3}"
```

In the above example the value of `x` is being type converted to an *intermediate* type before the object is created. This either yields an array like result or an empty object.

What are these rules?

Comment: Numbers and booleans can't be used with the spread operator. `..."abc" = ["a","b","c"]`, `...[1,2,3] = [1,2,3]`, but `...true` or `...123` will throw `Uncaught TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator`. They aren't iterable.

Comment: `123` and `true` are not iterables?

Comment: Well first, it's not `object destructoring`, is spread syntax.. -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: @Keith that might answer my question. Thanks.

Comment: @Keith so deconstruction is for assignments only, right? `var {a, ...b} = c`?

Comment: Can think of it basically the same as `console.log( Object.assign({},x) )`

Comment: this is about memory usage, string uses multiples bytes, simple integer only one, so they are not "deconstructive"

Comment: @Reactgular That's correct, though they aren't always so explicit in the wild. For example, `array.map(({key2}) => key2);` uses destructuring to grab only a single key value from an object argument.

Comment: @Reactgular Yes, *destructuring* is the target of an assignment (or parameter declaration etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule (detailed in [§7.3.23 of the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-copydataproperties)) is pretty simple: convert to an object (like `Object(x)` does) and copy the enumerable own properties. It's exactly the same what happens in `Object.assign({}, x)`.

The string `"abc"` is converted to a `new String("abc")` object which has indexed properties for each character. The number `123` and the boolean `true` are converted to `new Number(123)` and `new Boolean(true)` respectively, neither of which has any own properties. The array `[1,2,3]` already is an object and has indexed properties for each array element.